# Visual studio 2012's command arguments in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, args

I'm having a problem with getting bunch of files from the very start of my program ("args argv"),
when i run the program: one file is from the ProjectDir and the other one is from sub folder in my projectdir

here is a printscreen of my project properties:

[image]

help! please!

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little? And can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows your problem?

Comment: To clarify @JoachimPileborg's request, what exactly does "getting bunch of files" mean? What did you expect, what happened, and what did you do to get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't have to separate params with a `,`, they're separated with a space character
2. assuming that `file.txt` is from a sub-directory: you pass a path that points to the directory right **above** the `$(ProjectDir)`, not **below** the `$(ProjectDir)`

Assuming you have this directory structure

```
ProjectDir
  |
  +- johai.txt
  |
  +- subdir1
       |
       +- file.txt
```

you would pass these parameters as

```
subdir1/file.txt johai.txt
```

Comment: file.txt is actually from the project dir but the next file: johai.txt is from subdirectory of the project, what i'm trying to do is just read from files from the project dir.

Comment: @user3805152: `subdir1/johai.txt file.txt`

Comment: @user3805152 If you want to provide details essential to giving an answer, please do so in the question.

Comment: well, I figure it out, just by remove the / and the dots
but thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are delimited by spaces. You have a stray comma in your command line. Instead of

```
..\file.txt  ,  johai.txt
```

which actually specifies three arguments: `"..\file.txt"`, `","` and `"johai.txt"`. Instead 
you should simply write

```
..\file.txt johai.txt
```

for your command line.

Note that `..\file.txt` specifies a file in the parent directory of your project folder rather than a sub-folder. Perhaps that what you intended and just mis-spoke in the question.